# Express the following in terms of y.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $y = 2^{2x}$, express the following in terms of y.

$2^{2x-1} - 4^{2x+1} + 16^{x-1}$

I began it in this way:

$2^{2x}\cdot 2^{-1} - (2^2)^{2x+1} + (2^4)^{x-1}$

$2^{2x}\cdot \frac{1}{2} - 2^{4x}\cdot2^2 + 2^{4x}\cdot2^{-1}$

$2^{2x}\cdot\frac{1}{2}-2^{2x}\cdot2^{2x}\cdot2^2+2^{2x}\cdot2^{2x}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{y}{2} - 4y^2 + \frac{y^2}{2}$

Is this right?

Comment: Please use `\cdot` instead of the decimal point ".", e.g.

$2^{2x}\cdot 2^{-1} - (2^2)^{2x+1} + (2^4)^{x-1}$

Comment: Oh...alright. I didn't know...sorry. :(

Comment: edited. :) @AméricoTavares

Comment: That's fine. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. Note that $$(2^4)^{x-1}=2^{4(x-1)}=2^{4x-4}=2^{4x}\cdot2^{-4}\ne2^{4x}\cdot 2^{-1}.$$ Also note that you can gather like terms (specifically, the $y^2$ terms).

Comment: Oh...thank you so much!!! :)